# Implement custom dispose for AddScoped services in .NET Core built-in DI Container

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, dispose

I want to register a [TelemetryClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient?view=azure-dotnet) in a ServiceCollection using the AddScoped method and call `Flush` when the client is disposed. I don't have access to the `TelemetryClient` after the scope is finished to call it explicitly, and also I need to pass the `TelemetryClient` to a method of a third party method so I cannot use a wrapper.

I'm using the built-in Di container of .Net Core in Azure Functions.

I'm registering it like this:

```
services.AddScoped(x =>
            {
                return new TelemetryClient();
            });
```

I would like to have a method like [OnRelease](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html#onrelease) in Autofac, so I could register it like the following. Notice the call to `OnRelease`:

```
services.AddScoped(x =>
            {
                return new TelemetryClient();
            }).OnRelease(x=>
            {
                x.Flush();
            });
```

Comment: What is this third-party library? Just out of curiosity I'd like to see if the source code is available (even if that means decompiling) to see if it really doesn't flush the `TelemetryClient` after using it.

Comment: Its Serilog. The method is `Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSinkConfiguration.ApplicationInsightsEvents`

Comment: Looking at the [code and unit tests](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Tests/ApplicationInsightsTest.cs) it appears that you can configure Serilog by providing the configuration values it needs to create a `TelemetryClient`. Then it creates its own instance of that client. This is the sort of normal behavior I'd expect. Your code just depends on an `ILog` interface, and behind the scenes Serilog implements by creating and writing to a `TelemetryClient`. I doubt that you have to worry about flushing it.

Comment: @scott-hannen thanks and sorry for the late reply. I searched in the source code of Serilog and couldn't find the implementation of `ApplicationInsightsEvents`. I will use the method 'as is' for now. If I find any issues with it (messages not being sent) I will look for another alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the `TelemetryClient` like this:

```
public interface ILogsStuff
{
    void LogSomething(string message);
}

public class TelemetryClientLogger : ILogsStuff, IDisposable
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public TelemetryClientLogger(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

    public void LogSomething(string message)
    {
        _telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _telemetryClient.Flush();
    }
}
```

There's an added benefit, which is that whatever class you're injecting this into won't depend directly on `TelemetryClient`. You can define an interface that describes whatever you want to use the client for, and that's easier to both mock and replace with some other implementation if needed.

The [suggestion was made](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/596) to make `TelemetryClient` implement `IDisposable` and have it call `Flush()` when disposed, and this was the recommended solution.

---

The update to your question says:

> I need to pass the TelemetryClient to a method of a third party method so I cannot use a wrapper.

That changes things somewhat, as now the intention is not to *use* the `TelemetryClient` but to resolve it and then pass it to a method of a 3rd-party library. That's peculiar because it means that this library forces code that uses it to have a hard dependency on `TelemetryClient`, and then presumably doesn't handle that client as expected.

At this point there are still solutions, but they're all ugly because they are solutions to a weird problem that shouldn't exist (and wasn't created by your code.)

If you're passing `TelemetryClient` to a method, that method writes to it, and then it must be flushed, why doesn't that library flush it?

You can likely solve that problem by passing the `TelemetryClient` to the method when you execute it and then flushing the client after the method executes.

```
CallSomeMethod(someArgument, _telemtryClient);
telemetryClient.Flush();
```

Or, to get the result closer to your question, you could do this, which would obtain the result but is still awkward and weird:

```
public class TelemetryClientWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public TelemetryClientWrapper(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }

    public TelemetryClient Client => _telemetryClient;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _telemetryClient.Flush();
    }
}
```

You can inject this class and pass it to the library's method like this:

```
CallSomeMethod(someArgument, _telemtryClientWrapper.Client);
```

The problem now is that your class has a hard dependency on `TelemetryClient` *even though it doesn't use it*, all so it can fix what the other library (presumably) isn't doing correctly with that client.

Having said all of that, perhaps in your scenario [this is the answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

> The built-in service container is meant to serve the needs of the framework and most consumer apps. We recommend using the built-in container unless you need a specific feature that it doesn't support. Some of the features supported in 3rd party containers not found in the built-in container:

In other words, if you need what Autofac does, you can [still use Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection) with `IServiceCollection`.

Comment: Thanks @scott-hannen. The thing is that in my case a I need to pass the `TelemetryClient` to a method of a third party library, so I cannot use a wrapper. I should've been more clear in my question, I will update it.

Comment: Is it open source, or a library that you have control over? Ideally if it's asking you for a `TelemetryClient` it should already be ensuring that the client gets flushed. If the library is just asking you for a `TelemetryClient` then there's no way to tell that library what to do with it.